# PHP get variables outside method scope

Tags: php, scope, anonymous-function

i have this class (simple one just for example):

```
<?
class Test {
  public function test1($a) {
    $gen = function() {
      $gen = function() {
        global $a; // no effect
        echo 'a='. $a; // how could i access $a from test1 parameter without passing?
      };
      $gen();
    };
    $gen();
  } 
};

$x = new Test();
$x->test1(123);
```

is there a way to access $a from test1 paramter inside last $gen function without passing it to the $gen() function?

Comment: I'm confused as to why you would *want* to access it without passing

Comment: just for syntaxtic sugar

Comment: @KiswonoPrayogo this code does not set value `123` to the function. See the example http://codepad.viper-7.com/8koTDz

Comment: yes, it is not.. the answer below is one i wanted :3 thanks anyway

Comment: if i pass the $a i would have to type it 4 times, using use keyword, i only need to write 2 times :3 *this is one that i've been seeking*

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the `use` statement. Refere to the 3rd example on PHP's [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) on closures.

This will work:

```
<?php

class Test {
  public function test1($a) {
    $gen = function() use ($a) {
      $gen = function() use($a) {
        echo 'a='. $a; // how could i access $a from test1 parameter without passing?
      };
      $gen();
    };
    $gen();
  } 
};

$x = new Test();
$x->test1(123);
```

Answer (score 2):

Anonymous functions in PHP don't have an implicit variable scope like JavaScript does, so you need to specify which variables from the parent scope are needed. You do this with the `use` syntax:

```
$var = 123;
$fn = function() use ($var) {
    // you can use $var here
}
$fn();
```

See also: [Closures and scoping](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php#example-165)